Material React Table Large collapsible Table rows with virtualization enabled causes scroll lag along with an error
Large collapsible Table rows with virtualization enabled causes scroll lag along with an error (ResizeObserver loop completed with undelivered notifications)
I require to render very large amounts of data without pagination (~50k rows & 14 columns). Currently I have tested it with ~1200 rows and the browser basically freezes. The table has 5 editable cells with editing mode as cell. I am using Mui elements such as Inputs, TextFields, AutoComplete & Menus for the editable state.
When rowVirtualization is enabled the performance does get better but there is a very significant lag on scrolling.
Below is my MRT component
export const MaterialDataTable = <T extends MRT_RowData>(
  props: MaterialDataTableProps<T>,
) => {
  const {
    columns,
    data,
    tableId = "table",
    columnOrder,
    rowChangeHandler,
    getRowId,
    getSubRows,
    expandAll,
    height = "500px",
    highlightRow = -2,
    enableEditing = false,
  } = props;

  const [rowSelection, setRowSelection] = useState<MRT_RowSelectionState>({});
  const [MRTcolumnOrder, setMRTColumnOrder] = useState([
    ...columnOrder.map((c) => c.Id),
  ]);
  const columnVisibilityObj = columnOrder.reduce((acc, c) => {
    acc[c.Id] = true;
    return acc;
  }, {});
  const [columnVisibility, setColumnVisibility] = useState(columnVisibilityObj);

  useEffect(() => {
    setMRTColumnOrder(["mrt-row-expand", ...columnOrder.map((c) => c.Id)]);
    setColumnVisibility(
      getNewColumModel(columnVisibility, columnVisibilityObj),
    );
  }, [columnOrder]);

  useEffect(() => {
    table.toggleAllRowsExpanded(expandAll);
  }, [expandAll]);

  const table = useMaterialReactTable({
    columns,
    data,
    enableExpanding: props.enableExpanding ?? false,
    enableRowSelection: props.enableRowSelection ?? false,
    enableColumnActions: false,
    enableExpandAll: false,
    enablePagination: false,
    editDisplayMode: "cell",
    enableEditing: enableEditing,
    getSubRows: (originalRow: any) => originalRow.children,
    getRowId: getRowId,
    enableRowVirtualization: true,
    enableColumnVirtualization: true,
    muiTableBodyRowProps: ({ row }) => ({
      //implement row selection click events manually
      onClick: () => {
        setRowSelection((prev) => ({
          [row.id]: !prev[row.id],
        }));
        rowChangeHandler(row);
      },
      selected: rowSelection[row.id],
      sx: {
        cursor: "pointer",
        backgroundColor: highlightRow?.toString() == row.id ? "#d1d1d1" : "",
      },
    }),
    muiTableContainerProps: (table) => ({
      style: {
        height: height,
      },
    }),
    onRowSelectionChange: setRowSelection,
    onColumnOrderChange: setMRTColumnOrder,
    onColumnVisibilityChange: setColumnVisibility,
    state: {
      rowSelection,
      columnOrder: MRTcolumnOrder,
      columnVisibility,
    },
  });

  return <MRT_TableContainer table={table} id={tableId} />;
};

And below is an example of how my data looks like
{
    "id": 3,
    "substanceName": " Exernal battery with cables, Black outer cable jacket 1",
    "casNumber": null,
    "declaredMass": 12.465,
    "rollupMass": 12465,
    "calculatedMass": null,
    "resultMass": 12465,
    "unitOfMeasure": "g",
    "percentage": 0,
    "declaredPPM": null,
    "calculatedPPM": null,
    "thresholdPPM": null,
    "overThreshold": null,
    "disclosure": null,
    "exemptions": [],
    "exemptionId": [],
    "conversionFactor": null,
    "exemptionExpirationDate": null,
    "declaredCompliance": null,
    "calculatedCompliance": "Compliant",
    "substanceType": "Subpart",
    "unknown": false,
    "icon": "oj-ux-ico-data-segment oj-icon-color-success",
    "parent": null,
    "childLevel": 1,
    "rowId": 3,
    "errorIcon": false,
    "materialCategory": null,
    "children": [
        {
            "id": 4,
            "substanceName": "Polymer",
            "casNumber": null,
            "declaredMass": 12.465,
            "rollupMass": 12465,
            "calculatedMass": null,
            "resultMass": 12465,
            "unitOfMeasure": "g",
            "percentage": 0,
            "declaredPPM": null,
            "calculatedPPM": null,
            "thresholdPPM": null,
            "overThreshold": null,
            "disclosure": null,
            "exemptions": [],
            "exemptionId": [],
            "conversionFactor": null,
            "exemptionExpirationDate": null,
            "declaredCompliance": null,
            "calculatedCompliance": "Compliant",
            "substanceType": "Material",
            "unknown": false,
            "icon": "oj-ux-ico-ifc oj-icon-color-danger",
            "parent": 3,
            "childLevel": 2,
            "rowId": 4,
            "errorIcon": false,
            "materialCategory": null,
            "children": [
                {
                    "id": 5,
                    "substanceName": "POLYESTER RESIN",
                    "casNumber": "68604-67-1",
                    "declaredMass": 100,
                    "rollupMass": 12465,
                    "calculatedMass": null,
                    "resultMass": 12465,
                    "unitOfMeasure": "%",
                    "percentage": 100,
                    "declaredPPM": null,
                    "calculatedPPM": 1000000,
                    "thresholdPPM": null,
                    "overThreshold": null,
                    "disclosure": null,
                    "exemptions": [],
                    "exemptionId": [],
                    "conversionFactor": null,
                    "exemptionExpirationDate": null,
                    "declaredCompliance": null,
                    "calculatedCompliance": "Compliant",
                    "substanceType": "Substance",
                    "unknown": true,
                    "icon": "oj-ux-ico-beaker oj-icon-color-warning",
                    "parent": 4,
                    "childLevel": 3,
                    "rowId": 5,
                    "errorIcon": false,
                    "materialCategory": null
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}

another issue that occurs is that on the first load I get the following error

I think row virutalization is rendering rows as I scroll down but at a time a maximum of 10 rows are displayed on my screen and that shouldn't be much of a problem yet the lag is pretty significant
